# Addon development for google drawings

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to add templates to Google Drawings to extend the existing pallette. Does anyone know if this is possible? Are there API's for creating addons for Google Drawings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are yet no APIs for google drawing right now. You cannot create an add-on for Google Drawings up to this date as there is no *tools > script editor* available for google drawings neither it has any [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).